# Opening new page in PHP via <a href> with mysql host

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

Basically I've connected my PHP to the mysql database which loads a bunch of users names. I want to be able to click on any of the users name so I've hyperlinked them all through a while loop and . When I click one of the links it opens a new page but I would like to be able to tell which username I clicked on. I think I could do this by using $_GET but I'm getting the following errors:

```
<a href="usersProfile.php?firstname=<?php echo $first; ?>&lastname=<?php echo $last; ?>"><?php echo "$first" . " " . "$last";?></a>;
```

Also, what should I write in the new page? So far on the new page this is what I've wrote:

```
$first=$row['FName'];
$last=$row['LName'];

echo "USERNAME: " . "$first";
```

UPDATE:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td><b><center><a href='usersProfile.php?firstname=" .$first . "&lastname=" . &last . "">.$info['Name']."</a></td></center></b>
 </tr>";
```

This also gives error, but I think it shouldn't? Maybe I've made a simple mistake with the " somewhere, please check if you can find

Comment: Looks like the error is `&last` which I think is supposed to be `$last`

Comment: I think using the {$var} in long string like this make it easier to read. This should work: `echo "<tr>
    <td><b><center><a href='usersProfile.php?firstname={$first}&lastname={&last}'>{$info['Name']}</a></td></center></b>
 </tr>";`

Comment: When trying to get help, don't just say it gives an error - include the error in your question.

Answer (score 2):

In your new page you would check `$_GET` variable to see if the keys are set.

You have link with usersProfile.php?**firstname**=somename&**lastname**=somelastname so the keys you are looking for are `firstname` and `lastname`.

You would have to check if the key is set in order to avoid getting undefined indexes.

Ex. `$firstname = isset($_GET['firstname']) ? $_GET['fisrtname'] : null;`

This checks if the key is set and if it is sets `$firstname` to the data from the url otherwise to `null`

Comment: I have a link thats usersProfile.php I've added that firstname and lastname by experimenting so I'm not sure if I need them, so yeah can you please modify your answer and tell me step by step how I could get this to work, also on the new page what do you mean check $_GET? Like just write that there in the first line or smthing?

Comment: `$_GET` is a superglobal variable that holds the current data passed from the query string (everything after the ?) in the url (in your case the first and last name). You would use that code inside of usersProfile.php wherever you need to. I can't write the whole script for you. You may want to pass the id in the url as well to make querying extra information about the user on userProfile.php easier.

Comment: Please check my modified post, it gives me error still, and also I've added that Ex. you told me about in the new page!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it appears that you are trying to create a link for each user that will send you to a different or personal page when clicked.

In that case, it might be easier to simply query the entire table and have that set up in your html page as a separate .

For instance:

```
//Database connections

$query="SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE firstName = $firstname and lastName = $lastName";
//Change the query to whatever you want

$result = mysql_query($query)
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo "<a href='somepage.php'>" . $row['Username'] . "</a>";
}
```

This is just an example and a good amount would need to be added to it, but this more than likely would be easier for what you are trying to do. In this case, the loop would output all the names you have pulled from the database.